# Lua userdata: Unable to have simultaneous array access and methods

Tags: c, api, lua, metatable, lua-userdata

I had this guy's problem:
[Lua userdata array access and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970316/lua-userdata-array-access-and-methods)

wherein when I set the __index of my userdata's metatable, it always called the getter, instead of my other methods that weren't declared for meta-events. The solution to the above link is in Lua, and I attempted a C implementation which seems inelegant, but regardless, it creates a new problem in that my new methods can no longer take arguments, and I get this error:

`attempt to call method 'asTable' (a table value)`

on this Lua statement:

`print_r(c:asTable() )`

This is how I set everything up:

```
//Methods, many of which are overridden Lua meta-events (with the underscores)
static const struct luaL_reg vallib_m [] = {
    {"asTable", PushLuaTable}, //these functions are not called
    {"asCopy", CopyLuaVal}, 

    {"__newindex", SetLuaVal},
    {"__index", GetLuaVal},
    {"__tostring", ValToString},
    {"__gc", GarbageCollectVal},
    {"__metatable", HideMetaTable},

    {NULL, NULL}
};

//Static library functions
static const struct luaL_reg vallib_f [] = {
    {"specialprint", PrintVals}, 
    {NULL, NULL}
};


int luaopen_custom(lua_State *L)
{
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "custom.Value");
    lua_pushstring(L, "__index");
    lua_pushvalue(L, -2);  /* pushes the metatable */
    lua_settable(L, -3);  /* metatable.__index = metatable */

    luaL_register(L, NULL, vallib_m);
    luaL_register(L, "special", vallib_f);

    return 0;
}
```

Then in my getter, which is called by default (via __index), I first check for other events that I intended to be called and transfer control to them as follows. Note that I remove the argument containing the name of the function from the stack.

```
//TODO: this is a tentative fix, I would rather do this with metatables
//checking for methods
if (lua_isstring(L, 2))
{
    field = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
    if (unlikely(!field))
    {
        reporter->Warning("Fail in getter -- bad string as method attempt");
        return LUA_FAILURE;
    }

    if (strcmp(field, "asTable") == 0)
    {
        lua_remove(L, 2); //delete string "asTable"
        return PushLuaTable(L);
    }
    else if (strcmp(field, "asCopy") == 0)
    {
        lua_remove(L, 2); //delete string "asCopy"
        return CopyLuaVal(L);
    }
    //... other methods. 
    else
    {
        //Insert string back into stack??
    }

}
```

It doesn't treat my method as a function regardless of how many arguments are passed, and throws an error if there are even any parentheses or a colon. (It can be accessed by `c.asTable`, which works fine for methods that takes no arguments but I plan to add some that do, and regardless, the syntax is inconsistent with methods.

In any case, it would be preferable to NOT call these functions through my C getter, and instead solve this with metatables. If this is possible, please provide an example using the C API -- there are already StackOverflow solutions in Lua, but I haven't been able to translate them to C.

Comment: See second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957701/how-to-store-a-value-type-in-a-userdata/29967658#29967658).

Comment: That's helpful, thanks

Comment: A bit complex though -- So in my case, I would call moon_propindex(L, vallib_m, setLuaVal?, ?) ? It would be great if you could elaborate in a more general context and I'll mark it as a solution

Comment: Hi @siffiejoe, I used the moon toolkit to register my methods shown above using def_moonobject( L, "custom.Value, vallib_m, sizeof(vallib_m), 0) )
and I'm seeing the exact same behavior with asTable not being recognized. vallib_m is unchanged. Is there anything obvious I am missing for usage?

Comment: @siffiejoe sorry, final detail: in moon_defobject, I deleted the definition of all the __meta properties that overlapped with ones in vallib_m

Comment: @Leo: I edited my question (the one you refered to) and added the C code I wrote back then.  Hope it helps.  Feel free to ask, although it has been 2 years since I wrote those lines...

Comment: @1k5 Thank you, much appreciated! That was very simple, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing fields of a C struct from Lua you'll need a function as the `__index` metamethod, because you need access to the userdata object, and you won't get it if `__index` is a table:

```
-- Lua example code; obj* should be userdatas ...
-- an example __index function
local function anIndex( o, k )
  print( "accessing", k, "in", o )
  return 1
end

local obj = {}
local meta = { __index = anIndex }
setmetatable( obj, meta )
print( obj )
--> table: 0xfcb060
print( obj.x )
--> accessing x in  table: 0xfcb060
--> 1
```

This works fine for properties, but it's uncomfortable (and inefficient) for accessing methods shared by all userdatas of the same type. An `__index` table would be better for that:

```
-- an example method
local function aMethod( o )
  print( "calling aMethod on", o )
  return 2
end

local obj2 = {}
local methods = { aMethod = aMethod }
local meta2 = { __index = methods }
setmetatable( obj2, meta2 )
print( obj2 )
--> table: 0xfcada0
print( obj2:aMethod() )
--> calling aMethod on  table: 0xfcada0
--> 2
```

But now we want both!

Metamethods can be chained in Lua, so we could try to set an `__index` function as fallback for the `__index` table (`methods` in this case):

```
setmetatable( methods, meta )
print( obj2 )
--> table: 0xfcada0
print( obj2.x )
--> accessing x in  table: 0xfcade0
--> 1
print( obj2:aMethod() )
--> calling aMethod on  table: 0xfcada0
--> 2
```

But if you look closer, you'll see that the `__index` function gets a different object than `obj2` ...

```
print( methods )
--> table: 0xfcade0
```

It gets the `methods` table as the first argument instead. So we lose access to the original userdata (table in this example), and we can't actually look up any fields. So that won't work.

```
setmetatable( methods, nil ) -- let's undo this ...
```

Fortunately, an `__index` function can do arbitrary things, including accessing another table (e.g. one that's stored in an upvalue):

```
local obj3 = {}
local meta3 = {
  __index = function( o, k )
    local v = methods[ k ]  -- methods is an upvalue here
    if v == nil then
      print( "accessing", k, "in", o )
      v = 1
    end
    return v
  end
}
setmetatable( obj3, meta3 )
print( obj3 )
--> table: 0xfc23a0
print( obj3.x )
--> accessing x in  table: 0xfc23a0
--> 1
print( obj3:aMethod() )
--> calling aMethod on  table: 0xfc23a0
--> 2
```

Now this worked great! 
In case this happens more often, we could write a helper function that creates an appropriate `__index` function for us. The `indexfunc` that's passed as argument is only concerned with field lookup, and doesn't have to handle methods at all. The generated function will do that:

```
local function makeindex( methodstable, indexfunc )
  return function( o, k )
    local v = methodstable[ k ]
    if v == nil then
      v = indexfunc( o, k )
    end
    return v
  end
end

local obj4 = {}
local meta4 = { __index = makeindex( methods, anIndex ) }
setmetatable( obj4, meta4 )
print( obj4 )
--> table: 0xfc92b0
print( obj4.x )
--> accessing x in  table: 0xfc92b0
--> 1
print( obj4:aMethod() )
--> calling aMethod on  table: 0xfc92b0
--> 2
```

If you try to translate that to the Lua C API, you'll see that it's more convenient to take a `luaL_Reg` array instead of a methods table, and a `lua_CFunction` pointer instead of a stack index to a Lua function. And this is what the `moon_propindex()` function linked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957701/how-to-store-a-value-type-in-a-userdata/29967658#29967658) answer does (additionally it let's you set upvalues for all methods like `luaL_setfuncs()`).

Comment: 1k5 essentially did this in C except using rawget to prevent recursion, and that translation helped me solve my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970316/lua-userdata-array-access-and-methods

Comment: That prevents you from using an `__index` metamethod on the methods table, e.g. for inheritance. If you get infinite recursion, it's a bug in how you set up your metatables, not a matter of raw vs. non-raw access to the methods table.